# Does elasticsearch change data type considering the input

Tags: elasticsearch, cypher, kibana

I have the following mapping for a document to be index but the query returns the result as different data type that is numeric data type whereas it must be textual mapping.

```
Put my_index
    {
     "mappings": {
           "id" :
        {
          "type": "text"
        } 
       } 
    }
```

whereas output is

```
"id":123123123123
```

it must be

```
   "id":"123123123123"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the data in the original index request contained an integer, not a string. The value is still stored in the inverted index as a string (after applying whichever analyzers are specified for the field, in this case the standard analyzer which is the default for "text"), but the document source that's returned, is exactly the value that it received when you indexed it.

You can solve this either in the code where you make the index request (cast to a string before indexing), or you can use an ingest node (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) and convert processor (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html).

Also, it's not a great idea to use "text" type for ids -- I think you probably meant to use "keyword" (which isn't analyzed).